# Azure DevOps .NET Core build and publish doesn't keep given application version

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, build, azure-devops, versioning

I've an ASP.NET Core application I'm publishing on a dedicated server via Azure DevOps build/release pipelines.

I'm managing the application version number with the GitVersion task (`gittools.gitversion.gitversion-task.GitVersion@4`) in the YAML build.

The build step is something like:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: build
    workingDirectory: src/MyAppProjectFolder
    arguments: '-p:Version=$(GitVersion.FullSemVer)'
```

And is correctly generating the .exe with the given FullSemVer (I'm inspecting the Azure agent work folder)

Then I've the publish step:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    arguments: '--output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) --no-restore --no-build'
    workingDirectory: src/MyAppProjectFolder
```

For some reason the same .exe i found in the C:\agent_work\1\a\a.zip created by the publish DOESN'T have the correct version number, but the generic 1.0.0.

If I "emulate" the pipelines manually on the same server (with `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish` manually via powershell, same parameters) everything works as expected.

What's going on? Is there a way to ensure the application to keep the $(GitVersion.FullSemVer) version?

**Note**: I had to add

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .Net Core sdk 2.1.x'
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: 2.1.x
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
    includePreviewVersions: true
```

in front of each NET Core task, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops), after the agents have been updated to .NET Core 3.0 (before these builds worked well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `-p:Version=$(GitVersion.FullSemVer)` to your arguments for the publish step.

Comment: It's working! Even if I took another way in the end: the problem seems to be related to the tasks "UseDotNet@2", so to avoid them I just locked down the SDK verision on the project adding a global.json.